# How to integrate WPF and AKKA

Tags: wpf, actor-model, akka

I'm new to AKKA and i can't figure out a general proper way to integrate a backend actor system with my WPF views.

I studied a few examples i found (all very similar, probably based on [this](https://github.com/AaronLenoir/AkkaAndWpfExample)), but in my opinion they can't be really taken as a guideline.

How do you tipically make an actor system and WPF communicate?

Comment: WPF is just a display technology; your communication with the backend system (of which AKKA is a part) takes place in your Model (the "M" of MVVM).  WPF doesn't care about your Actors; any interaction with the UI takes place the same way it would without the Actor model.  There might be some threading implications (WPF uses a Single-Threaded Apartment; changes from other threads must be marshalled onto WPF's main thread using `Invoke()` to be displayed on the UI).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you sure it takes place in the model? My actor system lives between the model and the viewmodel actually. it turns out there's must be some kind of bridge between the viewmodel and the actor and setting it up seems quite messy

Comment: `My actor system lives between the model and the viewmodel actually.`  -- No it doesn't.  It's just considered part of the model.

Comment: My model is a database entity. I doubt an actor system should live there.

Comment: The database (and the data layer, and the service layer and the business layer and your Actors) are all part of the **Model** in MVVM.  To differentiate your database model from the Model in MVVM, simply call it the "Database Model."

Comment: So the only thing you really need to figure out is "how can I get results from Akka in object form, so that I can bind that data to the UI elements of my WPF application?"  You already know how to do the binding, because you're already doing that with your database model.

Comment: As far as a "proper way" to make that happen, the integration between your UI and your Akka result objects should probably take place in your `ViewModel` objects.  See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_introduction.htm) for an example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, i'm working on your approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough detail in your question to give an exact answer.

Typically, some form of Socket communication is used.  The Actor model relies on receiving and sending messages.  So you have various choices of how you want to send messages between processes.  A quick Google search shows that you can use [Akka Remoting](http://getakka.net/articles/remoting/index.html) which seems to make the remote message passing transparent to your app.  You would need to include that both in your WPF project and the in the remote process you are trying to connect to.